# How to Remove and add namespace in one xsl-file

Tags: xslt, namespaces, cluster-computing, biztalk, pipeline

I’ve got two xsl-files connected to a pipeline in a BizTalk receive-location. One removes namespace from the received message and one adds namespace to it. Since the BizTalk application runs on a two-node cluster the xsl-files not always executes on the same node. That causes the message to be suspended. Is it possible to Remove and add namespace in one xsl-file?

I'm quite new in xslt, could someone give me a clue?

Here is the first xsl-code removing namespace:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
 exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text() | comment() | processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the second xsl-code adding namespace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var" version="1.0"  xmlns:utFil="http://www.healthxml.org/Schemas/CEN/1613/2001/01/LaboratoryServiceRequest">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" version="1.0"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri()='']">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.healthxml.org/Schemas/CEN/1613/2001/01/LaboratoryServiceRequest/kit">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are won't be far off by just using the XSLT to add namespaces, as it is not really adding namespaces to existing elements, but creating new elements with the same local name, but in your new namespace. You just need to change the template to do it for all elements, not just ones in no namespace

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" version="1.0"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.healthxml.org/Schemas/CEN/1613/2001/01/LaboratoryServiceRequest/kit">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text() | comment() | processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy />
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, you may have issues if you have two attributes with the same local name, but different namespaces, although such a situation might not be that common. For example:

```
<test xmlns:a="a" a:attr="1" attr="1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

So, what you're really doing is *changing* the namespace and I'm afraid you've made it a bit more complicated than in needs to be.

All you need is a **Schema with the new Target Namespace and Mapper file using the Mass Copy Functoid**.

For clarity, I am saying that you should **not be using custom xlst** as you don't need to, this can be done in one Map specified on the Port.

Also, that you have a two node cluster should not matter.  If it does, that indicates a completely different problem.